# How do I find which database uses a file

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, file

Using MS SQL Server 2005.

On one of our servers we're running out of room, so I'm going through the databases, shrinking, removing, backuping etc.

The largest file in the Data directory (an .mdf no less, not a .ldf) is not named according to our common naming-convention (it should reflect the database's name). I cannot move the file, so I know it's in use, but I have no idea which database uses it.

Is there a way of figuring this out other than traversing the many, many databases on this server?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

But that just gave me the files in use by the Master database.

**Edit**
I kept looking, and found the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysaltfiles
```

This lists the filenames and the names of the files in the context of the server. It also lists the dbid, but this does not seem to be the same as the database_id in sys.databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the files in use by the Master database since you have selected the master as your current database. If you don't have *that* many databases, you can traverse all databases manually and do the select on them.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM sys.master_files
```

Comment: I know, but there are 167 databases on this server.

Comment: The select you typed in actually works! It tells me the physical name of the file and which DB it links to. Thanks!